# NoClassDefFoundError messages differ with context

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

NoClassDefFoundError gives me different kinds of messages in different contexts

By contexts, I mean,

Context 1:
If I remove the `sapjco3.jar`, the message is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/xxx/AbapException
```

Context 2:
If I add the jar file in the webapp lib, the message is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xxx.xxx.CpicDriver
```

I understand `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown when a class is not found during runtime.

but why there is a difference in representing the class in the message, ie with a slash (path) and dot (package)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at javadoc for [NoClassDefFoundError exception,](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) you'll see it has two constructor, one of which is accepting a message as parameter.

So formatting of the name for the class not found is depending on the code throwing the exception .

I don't know sapjco, but maybe the two classes are loaded by differents class loaders...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxx/xxx/AbapException is missing. This is not in sapjco3.jar.

Suppose a.class and b.class are required and order of loading is a,b. if a and b are not in classpath you will first get a is missing. if a is added in the class path you will get b is missing. Hope that is clear.